# How to Disable : Authorise attribute automatically login the user

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm having an issue with identity server.

When unauthenticated If I try to access an action that has the authorize attribute I am taken to the login page to login(as expected)

After I logout then try to access an action that has the authorize attribute, I am given access.

After Logout When I access non secure action I can see that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false but when I try to access a secure action , I am granted access and I see that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true.

I assume that this is part of the functionality. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a bug

Log out Code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LogOut()
{         
     await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
     await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");    
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Changed to :

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return new SignOutResult(new[] { "Cookies", "oidc" });
}
```